# How can I accept TCP-connections at the same <ip:port> in many threads?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

How can I accept TCP-connections at the same `ip:port` in many threads in one process on Linux (kernel 3.16)?

Can I use for this one socket-acceptor per thread (i.e. 4 socket-acceptors in 4 threads)?

I.e. every thread has its own acceptor socket with the same `ip_addr:port`, instead of one acceptor socket shared for all threads.

Should I use `SO_REUSEPORT` and `SO_REUSEADDR` for this?

Comment: Just have all the threads accept from the same socket.

Comment: Re your edit, your 'i.e.' does not follow. There is no necessity for multiple listening sockets here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the exact same thing when writing my server.  You have a main method that accepts incoming connections to the machine, and threads to handle each connection.  Every time a new machine connects to the server, a new connection object is created. From your main method, you have to spawn a new thread for every connection, and pass that connection object as a parameter to the thread.  For example here's an abstraction:

```
void acceptConnections()
{
    while(true)
    {
        connection = socket.accept()
        createNewThread(threadMethod, connection)
    }
}
```

In the thread you spawned you can receive data from the connection object just like normal.  I cannot give more detail without knowing what language you are working in

Comment: Thank you, but I'm interested in the possibility to use number of acceptor sockets equal to the number of threads. I.e. every thread has its own acceptor socket with the same `ip_addr:port`, instead of one acceptor socket shared for all threads.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

1. You can't do this in TCP.
2. You don't need it. Just have all the threads accept from the same socket.